# convert numbers in scientific notation to decimal

Tags: c, scientific-notation

Write a C program to convert a number in scientific notation to its equivalent decimal form : 
Given 
8.3e+2 output = 830 
2.E-1  output = 0.2 
4.3E2  output = 430 
Is there any inbuilt library or function in C/C++ which can do this?
or one will have to write his own code, in that case, any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: First decide if you want a solution in C or C++, they are two very different languages. Secondly, what have you tried yourself? Please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions, for example to include a [mcve] of your attempt.

Comment: You might like to explore [`scanf()` formatting specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/scanf-type-field-characters?view=msvc-160) and [`printf()` formatting specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-160).

Comment: The question is what preconditions can be relied upon. E.g. should it be possible to convert 1.23e-100 into decimal form? What is the range of values needed to deal with?

Comment: @EricPostpischil The problem, now that you've removed the C++ tag, is that the accepted answer posted appears to be invalid. Maybe undo or change your edit?

Comment: @AdrianMole: It is up to OP to clarify whether they want C (in which case they should also remove acceptance of the answer) or C++ (in which case the tags should be changed). Vote to close for lack of clarity is fine too.

Comment: @Eric OK. Just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: what does OP refer to ?

Comment: @pensee: Original Poster. You should state whether you want a C or C++ solution. If you want C, you should remove acceptance of the current answer, as it is incorrect because it is C++. If you want C++, you should add the C++ tag, remove the C tag, and edit the question to refer only to C++, not C. They are different languages, have different rules, and should not mix them in questions except questions that involve interacting between the two or differences between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int32_t main(int32_t argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string str = "8.3e+2";
    std::cout << std::stod(str) << std::endl;
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This works with my compiler, but I have a question: why did you write this ```int32_t main, char *argv[]``` instead of just ```int main()```.  It seems like Java

Comment: C takes arguments from the command line, and this is how you catch them, argc is the number of arguments and argv is an array of strings with them.

Comment: @ACoelho There is nothing done with any command line arg. in this mcve. Btw. `int32_t main` instead `int main` is looking somehow strange to me too. (I don't think it's wrong...)

Comment: Thanks This seems to be working. I am a beginner at stackoverflow want to know few things - 1) For new line do we always have to type <br> ?? That was weird I couldnt get a newline without typing this tag.  Similarly more than one space directly doesnt work. dont know whats the tag for that. Using this question as an opportunity to learn about stackoverflow syntax.

Comment: Many text editors auto-complete main to this expression, and `int32_t` can be safer depending on the environment you are running, none of it is necessary for this example though.

Comment: `int32_t main` is wrong. C++ 2017 (draft n4659) 6.6.1 says `main` shall have a declared return type of `int`. It may be that `int32_t` is an alias of `int` (if `<cstdint>` is included), but this is not portable. Also, although the OP tagged C and C++ and wrote C/C++ in one place, they asked for a C program, so the balance lies with C, not C++.

Comment: @Harry How is it related to the `C` tag. It will not compile https://godbolt.org/z/8doYqz